# btrfs: checksum/header error at logical

Tags: linux, files, arch-linux, btrfs

I've been using BTRFS as my filesystem for almost two years now, completely without incident, however, yesterday, I ran into an issue where my file-system would automatically switch to read-only. If I restart my computer, it gets mounted properly in read-write mode, but then will automatically switch to read-only mode after a while. After much digging, I've pinned the problem down to a BTRFS error.

After running

```
btrfs scrub start /dev/sda5
```

I find the following in my `dmesg`

```
[  107.910348] BTRFS warning (device sda5): checksum/header error at logical 100470390784 on dev /dev/sda5, physical 36045881344: metadata leaf (level 0) in tree 7
[  107.910354] BTRFS warning (device sda5): checksum/header error at logical 100470390784 on dev /dev/sda5, physical 36045881344: metadata leaf (level 0) in tree 7
[  107.910364] BTRFS error (device sda5): unable to fixup (regular) error at logical 100470390784 on dev /dev/sda5
```

So there's something in the filesystem that is corrupt. I would also note that `/dev/sda5` is where my root partition is at. But, it seems that it can't be something vital since everything works totally fine most of the time. I guess something must be triggering disk access to the corrupt chunk or file every once in a while, making BTRFS freak out and switching over to read-only mode.

I've ran `btrfs scrub start /dev/sda5` two times now, the output being

```
UUID:             8b0f88e4-8fb2-4201-8cfa-ed08f40fb185
Scrub started:    Wed Sep 18 14:26:47 2019
Status:           finished
Duration:         0:03:56
Total to scrub:   101.19GiB
Rate:             439.09MiB/s
Error summary:    verify=1
  Corrected:      0
  Uncorrectable:  1
  Unverified:     0
```

Since `/dev/sda5` is my root partition, I can't really do anything while mounted. So I booted into the machine using a live USB and run `btrfs rescue zero-log /dev/sda5`, but this did not fix the problem.

Some other potentially useful information. I'm using Arch linux with 5.2.11-arch1-1-ARCH. I also suspected Dropbox may have been the culprit since I installed it a couple of days ago, but removing the program and deleting the dropbox folder did not fix the issue.

I've never dealt with this before and obviously, I can't reboot every time the system locks up into read-only mode. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does `smartctl` tell you about that disk? Specifically does it report any errors?

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully someone else can hope more than this partial answer, but:

Btrfs stores a checksum for each block used by the filesystem. That error message means that btrs read a block and the checksum didn't match. Normally that'd be a block of user (file) data, which is easy enough to fix (replace file from backup). However, in this case, it's a block of filesystem metadata.

Ideally, a corrupt checksum only happens due to hardware issues (e.g., "bit rot" on disk). And btrfs normally stores two copies of the metadata, even if there is only a single disk (metadata profile DUP). So `btrfs scrub` would normally fix this by looking at the other copy — which either you don't have (filesystem created or converted to metadata profile single) or alternatively both copies are corrupt.

The first thing you need to do (and really should have done before steps like `zero-log`) is make sure you have backups, especially of your important files.

After that, you could definitely get it working again by creating a new filesystem and copying the data over. The only other suggestion I can give is to [ask the btrfs mailing list](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Btrfs_mailing_list).